# How do they draw vectorized lines on web pages?

Tags: html, css, graphics, vector, svg

Projects such as google docs and yandex maps http://maps.yandex.ru/-/CFsgzMjN allow visitors to draw geometric figures on web pages. How did they do this without HTML5?

Is this always SVG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're using the `canvas`, look at the `.ymaps-overlay-transition-container`, it have the `canvas` tag inside it.

Comment: While the `canvas` tag is present in HTML5, it don't strictly require this doctype, so the `canvas` can be used anywhere, but it just won't be valid and, probably, could have some issues in it's realizations, however I don't think, that there are any differences in the use of `canvas` between different doctypes.

Answer (score 1):

This may be either SVG, or just drawing using the canvas. The doctype of a document need not be html5 for these features to work.

Comment: both SVG and canvas require HTML5?